# Grails binddata in service

Tags: grails

Is there a way to utilize `bindData` in a service other than using the deprecated `BindDynamicMethod`? I can't just use

```
TestObject testObject = new TestObject()
TestObject testObject.properties = params
```

or

```
TestObject testObject = new TestObject(params)
```

because I have a custom bind method utilizing the `@BindUsing` annotation within my `TestObject` class.

Comment: Yes, but the options are different for different versions of Grails.  What version of Grails are you interested in?

Comment: @JeffScottBrown I am using grails 2.4.4

Comment: I [don't see any of those methods marked as deprecated in Grails 2.4.4](http://grails.github.io/grails-doc/2.4.4/api/org/codehaus/groovy/grails/web/binding/DataBindingUtils.html).

Comment: @dmahapatro apologies i had to change that to `BindDynamicMethod`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In Grails 2.4.4 you can do something like this:

```
// grails-app/services/demo/HelperService.groovy
package demo

import org.grails.databinding.SimpleMapDataBindingSource

class HelperService {

    def grailsWebDataBinder

    TestObject getNewTestObject(Map args) {
        def obj = new TestObject()
        grailsWebDataBinder.bind obj, args as SimpleMapDataBindingSource
        obj
    }
}
```

Comment: This is exactly what I ended up going with! Thanks!

Answer (score 20):

If you are using Grails 3.* then the service class can implement [`DataBinder`](http://grails.github.io/grails-doc/3.0.x/api/grails/web/databinding/DataBinder.html) trait and implement `bindData()` as shown below example:

```
import grails.web.databinding.DataBinder

class SampleService implements DataBinder {

    def serviceMethod(params) {
        Test test = new Test()
        bindData(test, params)

        test
    }

    class Test {
        String name
        Integer age
    }
}
```

This is how I quickly tried that in grails console:

```
grailsApplication.mainContext.getBean('sampleService').serviceMethod(name: 'abc', age: 10)
```

Answer (score 0):

In 2.5, I found that emulating the behaviour of the Controller API in a helper service worked:

```
def bindData(def domainClass, def bindingSource, String filter) {
    return bindData(domainClass, bindingSource, Collections.EMPTY_MAP, filter)
}
def bindData(def domainClass, def bindingSource, Map includeExclude, String filter) {
    DataBindingUtils
        .bindObjectToInstance(
            domainClass, 
            bindingSource,
            convertToListIfString(includeExclude.get('include')),
            convertToListIfString(includeExclude.get('exclude')), 
            filter);
    return domainClass;
}
```

convertToListIfString is as per the controller method:

```
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
private List convertToListIfString(Object o) {
    if (o instanceof CharSequence) {
        List list = new ArrayList();
        list.add(o instanceof String ? o : o.toString());
        o = list;
    }
    return (List) o;
}
```